# display Notes text field containing html markup

Tags: html, xpages-ssjs

I want to display a Notes text field that contains HTML on an XPage.

I am struggling with the correct display.

The text is not 100% html, I mean it might contain html for mark-up () but all newlines are "normal" returns in a text field.

An alternative that I have used before is to place the computed text within a textarea field:

```
<textarea 
                                class="form-control" 
                                rows="10" 
                                placeholder="Textarea"
                                readonly="readonly" 
                                style="background-color:#FFF"></textarea>
```

But then I get a scroll bar which I would like to avoid in my case. Also here the HTML is not formatted but the newlines are respected.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this discussion:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/xpagesforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=EE43D8FF22664F4D852578D400727EF3

Add a convertor for your computed text like:

```
 <xp:this.converter>
            <xp:customConverter>
                <xp:this.getAsString><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(value, "\n", "<br />")}]]></xp:this.getAsString>
                <xp:this.getAsObject><![CDATA[#{javascript:@ReplaceSubstring(value, "\n", "<br />")}]]></xp:this.getAsObject>
            </xp:customConverter>
        </xp:this.converter>
```

I hope this helps